# how to find an IP of a gaming server

Tags: ip

I am trying to track the Modern Warfare Warzone server that I am connected.

Is there a way in command prompt to show the IP of the server I am connected to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the traffic between you and the server, you can use some tools like wireshark.